# Interacting with the Instagram web app in an iOS app can be difficult to automate,

Tags: javascript, appium

Interacting with the Instagram web app in an iOS app can be difficult to automate, as developers may need to use JavaScript or other workarounds  as Appium to simulate user interactions.

I'm afraid , any suggestion?

I want simulate post, like story ,comment